# Python: How to use for loop to call all the functions?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I want to use the f_i function like this:

```
for i in range (9):
    f_i(y)=c
```

But I don't know how to use the value of i to call all my ten functions. So what should I do?

Comment: Please show us the code to the f_i function.

Comment: Are you trying to build the name of the function dynamically?

Comment: If you have 10 functions and you are calling it in a for loop, which has the same behavior, that is bad code. You might wanna relook at the logic behind doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume functions is defined/imported into the current file.

`locals().get()` is the thing that you want

```
for i in range (9):
    func = locals().get("f_{}".format(i))
    func(y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a list containing the functions and use each function by using loop as follows.

```
def f1(x):
    return x

def f2(x):
    return x * 2

def f3(x):
    return x * 3

function_list = [f1, f2, f3]
for f in function_list:
    print(f(1))
```